# How to append progress bar on every div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here, I have a webpage in which I have so many divs.

All divs have the same id. but there is the type different.

Like the first div have type="timeline" and other is type="slideshow".

When I scroll on my type=timelime div I have progress bar shown on top. it works very fine but it only appends my progress bar at one div. My progress bar only works on when type equals to timeline.

What should I do to resolve this error?

Progress bar moves when timeline scroll on this everything work fine but I don't know why it does not append all progress bar with type=timeline.

like same I have a slideshow. I have three slideshows only third slideshow work very properly.

Here is my code.

```js
function isOnScreen(that){
 var win = $(window);
 var viewport = {
   top : win.scrollTop(),
   left : win.scrollLeft()
 };
 viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
 viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
 var bounds = that.offset();
 bounds.right = bounds.left + that.outerWidth();
 bounds.bottom = bounds.top + that.outerHeight();
 return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
   }
   
   $(window).scroll(function() {
  if(isOnScreen($("#slide"))) {
   $("#progressbar").show();
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isOnScreen($("#slide"))) {
     $("#progressbar").show();
     var scroll        = $(this).scrollTop();
     var height        =$('#slide').position().top;
     var percent       = (scroll- height) / 100;
   
     $("#progressbar").attr('value', parseInt(percent*6));
    } 
   });
  } else {
   $("#progressbar").hide();
  }   
 });

 var para = document.createElement("Progress");
 para.setAttribute('id', 'progressbar');
 para.setAttribute('value', 0);
 para.setAttribute('max', 100);
 // document.getElementById("slide").appendChild(para);
 
 $("[type=timeline]").addClass('timelineClass');
 let selectSection = document.querySelectorAll(".timelineClass");
 let selectLength = selectSection.length;

 for(i = 0;i < selectLength; i++){
  let data = selectSection[i].getAttribute('type');
  if(data=='timeline') {
   console.log("inside")
   selectSection[i].appendChild(para);
  }
 }
 
 var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');
 var myNodeList = divSlide.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < myNodeList; i++) {
  var type = divSlide[i].getAttribute("type");
  if (type == "timeline") {
  
  } else if (type == "slideshow") {
   var timeline = divSlide[i];         
   let sliderData = timeline.getElementsByTagName("section");
   timeline.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<a class="left  color_arrow carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" onclick = "plusDivs(-1, timeline)" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>');

   timeline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',' <a class="right color_arrows  carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  onclick = "plusDivs(1, timeline)" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');

   var slideIndex = 1;
   showDivs(slideIndex, timeline);
  }
 }
 function plusDivs(sliderItem, el) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += sliderItem, el, sliderItem);
 }

 function showDivs(sliderItem, el , dir) {

  let i;
  let sliderData = el.getElementsByTagName("section");
 
  if (sliderItem > sliderData.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (sliderItem < 1) {slideIndex = sliderData.length}

  for (i = 0; i < sliderData.length; i++) {
   sliderData[i].classList.add('hide')
   sliderData[i].classList.remove('active')  
   sliderData[i].classList.remove('animated')  
   sliderData[i].classList.remove('fadeInRight')  
  }

  sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.remove('hide')
  sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('active')
  sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('animated')
  if(dir === 1)
   sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('fadeInLeft')
  else if(dir === -1)
   sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('fadeInRight')
 }
```

```html
<
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="timeline" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>

<div type="slideshow" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
<div type="slideshow" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
   <section>
    <header>Title one</header>
    <article>Some data</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: id's must be unique. You have same id "slide" assigned to multiple divs

Comment: yes i have restrictions.to use same id and work on types. is there any way to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps adding a common class and operating on that class name would help? By default IDs are considered to be unique in the DOM

Comment: You can not have same id to multiple elements. You can assign same class to your divs and attach progressbar with it.